# Как загрузить файлы на GitHub?

Tags: git, github

Делаю курс Data Science Specialization курс на Coursera, с GitHub совсем не знаком. Как мне с mac залить 4 R файла и 4 PNG.

Нужно залить сюда: https://github.com/edkiljak/ExData_Plotting1/tree/master

Comment: суд по дате вопроса и по времени коммитов на гитхабе - вопрос больше не актуален?

Comment: 30000 форков! Впервые такое вижу :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev: репозиторий нужно форкнуть для учебного задания, насколько я понимаю)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, если у автора 30000 студентов, то респект ему большой :-)

Comment: @TagirValeev: на Courserа это нормальное количество. Вообще, удивительно, как сегодня расширились границы образования.

Answer (score 4):

Скачайте [клиент Github для OS X](https://desktop.github.com/) (Эта страница автоматически предлагает версию для вашей ОС).

Cделайте клон репозитория (используйте ваше имя):

[image]

Залейте в созданную папку нужные файлы и сделайте коммит:

[image]

После этого нажмите кнопку `sync`, все изменения будут загружены на гитхаб.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Человек спрашивал про Macintosh ((

Comment: Спасибо @NickVolynkin за корректировку инструкции под мак.

Comment: @Kill написали про мак)

Comment: Спасибо всем, вроде сделал, но хочется научиться конечно через terminal. В этом году начинаю учится на BSc Computer Science.Возможно там это будем проходить. В любом случае спасибо

Comment: @EdgarKiljak: как ваши успехи в изучении терминала?

Answer (score 2):

в *github*-е нет ничего загадочного. фактически это место хранения *git*-репозиториев (плюс ещё несколько удобных «штучек»).

так что просто добавьте нужные файлы в ваш *git*-репозиторий и отправьте обновления на *github*.